# How to enable userinteraction in tableview when coming back to tableview

Tags: iphone

In my app I am doing tableView. By clicking row, the new view will navigate. Before navigation of new view, application is processing data from server. Until processing of data finished, view will not navigate. In this time period I want to disable userinteraction of tableview, so user can not select further rows.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Note that, When I again come back to the tableview, user will again allowed to select any row.
I do not have any idea, how can I enable userinteracation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are getting your data asynchronously.
In this case, you can re-enable user interaction from your connection delegate method. If you are using NSURLRequest/NSUrlConnection, the delegate method would be: `connectionDidFinishLoading:` (don't forget also about `connection:didFailWithError:`).

From [NSURLConnection Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> connectionDidFinishLoading:
>
> Sent when a connection has finished loading successfully.

So, when the data is there and you are done with the processing, you re-enable the table view.

Comment: I am getting data asynchronously. But i have not defined any delegate methods. So i can not access tableView variable in the method connectiondidFinishLoading. And even if i implement delegate method, how would i access variable tableview.

Comment: If you have not defined `connectionDidFinishLoading`, what are you doing with the data you received?? As to how you can access your tableview from this delegate, it depends on what your delegate is. If your delegate is the same as your UITableViewController, then the table view is `self.tableView`.

Comment: Ok. i did it in the method, where i am parsing the data using the delegate which is same as UITableViewController. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Coming back after navigation, Put following sentence in your `viewWillAppear` That will again allow your table view user interaction to true.

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```